# WPF ICommand CanExecute get called even though there is a modal window

Tags: wpf, icommand, canexecute

Let's say I have an user control with a button

```
<UserControl>
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Show Dialog" DataContext="{Binding m_btnShowDialog}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonVM}" Command="{Binding Cmd}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" >
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The command class implements ICommand interface. 
When the focus is on the above dialog, the CanExecute sometimes get called. 
That is something to be expected.
The problem is when I click the button, the Execute method get called and a new modal dialog pops up. 
The focus should be on the new dialog but for some reasons, the CanExecute still get called when I interract with the new dialog.
Is that behavior normal?
And how can I override that behavior?
I don't want CanExecute method of commands attached to controls of parent dialog to be called when a child modal dialog is showing up.

Comment: You have to set the owner of the child window i.e. childWindow.Owner = parentWIndow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected. Quoting directly from WPF expert Josh Smith :

> WPF will automatically ask all of the commands being used in your UI
>   if they can execute. This happens at various times, such as when input
>   focus shifts to another control, an item is selected in a list, etc.
>   You can also programmatically trigger this to happen by calling the
>   CommandManager’s InvalidateRequerySuggested static method. This all
>   seems magical, dreamy, and almost too good to be true.

You can get more detailed and clear explanation [here](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/06/17/allowing-commandmanager-to-query-your-icommand-objects/)

You can override behavior using CanExecuteChanged event in your command implementation.

```
class MyCommand : ICommand
{
public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
return maybeTrueOrFalse;
}

public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}

public void Execute(object parameter)
{
// Do something awesome.
}
}
```